# Simplify Trig Expressions

Tags: trigonometry

I need to simplify $\sin^3(x)+\cos^2(x)\sin(x)$:
First thing I noticed was the pythagorean identity.
$$\sin(x)\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)\sin(x) \rightarrow \sin(x)(1)\sin(x)\rightarrow\sin^2(x),$$ 
but this doesn't work obviously.
This is where I am stuck, I just can't see any way to simplify.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're on the right track, but your algebra is going awry.  You rewrote $\sin^3 x+\cos^2 x\sin x$ as $\sin x\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x\sin x$, which is a good start.  Before you can use the Pythagorean identity, you should *factor out* the common $\sin x$: $$\sin x\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x\sin x=\sin x(\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x)$$
Now, apply the Pythagorean identity.